# Blur planes of 3D cv::Mat1f

Tags: opencv

I created three dimension matrix for computing of histogram as follows:

```
// Histogram of HSV image
int const hue_bins = 180; //
int const sat_bins = 256; //
int const val_bins = 4;   // Only four bins for V channel!
float const hue_range[2] = {0, 180};
float const sat_range[2] = {0, 256};
float const val_range[2] = {0, 256};
int const hsv_sizes[] = {hue_bins, sat_bins, val_bins};
cv::Mat1f m_tone_frequences(3, hsv_sizes, 0.);
```

Then I'm using

```
cv::calcHist
    ( &image, 1, channels, mask, histogram
    , num_channels, hsv_sizes, ranges);
...
cv::calcBackProject
    ( &image_f, 1, channels, histogram
    , backproject, hsv_sizes, 1.0);
```

and seems it works fine (code is simplified).

Since the histograms are sampled from a single image, it is possible to run into sampling problems (object of interest has narrow color distribution). So I want to apply Gaussian smoothing to "Value" histogram planes.
I'm tried get histogram rows, but it gives me anothed 3D Mat:

```
cv::Mat1f hrow = histogram.row(0); 
// hrow.dims ==3 && hrow.rows == -1 && hrow.cols == -1
```

and I don't have ideas about processing of it.

I am at a loss to solve this issue because this action should be very simple to do.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.